# Локализация _getch()

Tags: c++, консоль, input

Всем привет. Делаю змейку в консоли. Сейчас "локализовывал" её, чтобы работала и с английской, и с русской раскладкой.
Заметил интересную особенность функции _getch();
Такой вариант будет работать с русскими символами: switch(char(_getch())), а такой нет: switch(_getch()).
Кто знает с чем это связано?

P.S.
Также, если знаете, как сделать считывание определенной клавиши независимо от раскладки, будь то хоть японская, китайская или любая другая, дайте, пожалуйста, совет, или ссылку на информацию.

```
   void Input() {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            switch (char(_getch()))
            {
            case 'a':
            case 'ф':
                dir = LEFT;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'в':
                dir = RIGHT;
                break;
            case 'w':
            case 'ц':
                dir = UP;
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'ы':
                dir = DOWN;
                break;
            case 'x':
            case 'ч':
                gameOver = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да понять-то его, надежа-государь, немудрено... (с) `char`, он бывает и знаковый, и беззнаковый, от реализации зависит. Вот и приводим возврат `int` к нужному типу.

Answer (score 1):

> switch(char(_getch())), а такой нет: switch(_getch()). Кто знает с чем это связано?

_getch() возвращает `int`, а не `char`.

Для русской буквы 'а' c с кодом `E0` `integer` будет иметь значение `000000E0` , то есть 224. А `char` у Microsoft (вроде бы) знаковый, то есть при сравнении с `integer` значение `E0` типа `char` будет расширено до `FFFFFFE0`, то есть -32. Естественно что -32 не равно 224.

> как сделать считывание определенной клавиши независимо от раскладки

через WinAPI отслеживать события клавиатуры, которые присылают Scan Code, независимые от раскаладки.

Comment: Спасибо
Там английская a, но суть я понял

Answer (score 0):

Извращенец! Жесткий извращенец!!!

Для винды - `GetAsyncKeyState()` вернет VK для зажатой кнопки.

Для линухи - `/dev/input/by-path/*-kbd` - вернет состояние. Есть еще пару способов можно рассмотреть.

А вообще змейку на SDL сделать куда практичнее и интереснее будет.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState() - Я попробовал.
Удобно, что работает с любой раскладкой, но неудобно отслеживать был ли "клик". В этом плане проще с _getch(): один раз нажал - одно событие. Или есть какой-то элегантный способ с GetAsyncKeyState()?
Да, графику тоже потом планирую сделать. Версия для терминала как прототип будет.

Comment: P.S. Помогло ставить пустой цикл пока клавиша не отпущена. Правда есть опасения застрять в одном из таких в ненужный момент.

Comment: Основная проблема в том, что консольное окно не принадлежит приложению, оно принадлежит системе. Есть +100500 способов считать клавиши в режиме чтения eventов но большинство из них не работает. Кстати по поводу буфферов, вы мелкософтовские заметки читали,по этому поводу? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events

Comment: Почитал, спасибо.
Но меня устраивает вариант с GetAsyncKeyState(). 
Только вот я хочу добавить такую функцию: если нажата любая клавиша помимо клавиш управления, esc и enter, необходимо ставить игру на паузу. Знаю два варианта проверить есть ли нажатая клавиша: _kbhit() и GetKeyboardState().

Comment: У _kbhit() непонятно как очищать буфер, так как _getch() крайне неудобен, если лишний раз использовал, то прерывается игра для ввода, если один раз использовал, то неправильно считаются enter и esc. А GetKeyboard() у меня не получается использовать.

Comment: Пробовал проверять и с 60 по 90й элементы массива KeyBoardState как для VK и с 16 по 38й как для сканкодов

Comment: ChatGPT прекратил мои несколькодневные мучения. Вот самый нормальный вариант для _kbhit(): 
FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)). 
Я и сам пытался нагуглить подобную функцию, но результата ноль было, только всякие fflush() выскакивали.